How to manipulate the legend of 'scale_fill_gradientn'?
I'm trying to plot a map to represent a ranking of Mesoregions.
Here is my code:
library(geobr)
library(sf)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

conj_dados = list_geobr()

MA_reg <- read_meso_region(code_meso = 21, year = 2020)

#dataMA <- read.csv("C:/Users/ji_le/Downloads/Ranking_MA.csv", dec = ".", header = TRUE)

dataMA <- data.frame(state = c("Norte Maranhense", "Oeste Maranhense", 
                               "Centro Maranhense", "Leste Maranhense", 
                               "Sul Maranhense"), 
                     Ranking = c(4, 3, 5, 2, 1))

Ranking <- c(dataMA$Ranking)
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = MA_reg, aes(fill = Ranking), color = "black", size = .15) +
  labs(size = 8) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours=heat.colors(10, rev=TRUE),
    values=rescale(c(5,1)), name = "[Ranking]",
    limits=c(1,5),
    breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5)) + 
  theme_minimal()

Obtaining this following output:

However, as you can see, I can't manipulate the legend and its labels to get something more representative. I mean, instead of the values ​​being in descending order (from 5 to 1), I'd like them to be in ascending order (from 1 to 5). Of course, the same goes for the colors.
By the way, is there a way to turn these numbers into ordinals?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Your code does not run and has typos (data = MA_reg). Please include in your question the packages you are using (e.g., ggplot2, scales, etc).

Swap your limits to c(5, 1)? And you can use guide = guide_legend() in your scale to get a legend instead of a color bar.

Thanks for your feedback, @LMc. I think I've fixed the errors you pointed out.

Since you did not share your data, here is an example using the nc dataset. You can use scale_fill_manual to set directly the color palette and the order of the values on the legend of your plot. Additionally, you should convert your Ranking variable to factor, so that it is not interpreted as a continuous numeric scale in your legend.
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

MA_reg <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

set.seed(5)
# Add random Ranking values from 1 to 5 and convert to factor, so they are interpreted as factors (or discrete) instead of continuous.
MA_reg$Ranking <- as.factor(sample(1:5, nrow(MA_reg), replace = TRUE))

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = MA_reg, 
          aes(fill = Ranking), 
          color = "black", 
          size = .15) +
  labs(size = 8) + 
  # Use fill_manual to set the legend for discrete values
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = heat.colors(5, rev=FALSE),
    name = "[Ranking]",
    breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5)) + 
  theme_minimal()


